# Docker Compose Overriding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker Compose files, `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mongodb/data/db:/data/db
  redis:
    image: redis:3
    restart: always
  application:
    build: .
    image: localregistry:5000/mz_application:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
```

and another file used when I do deployment `docker-deploy.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  application:
    image: localregistry5000/mz_application:latest
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - application
    restart: always
    links:
      - application:application
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    tty: false
```

So the idea behind using those files is as follows. When I run

```
docker-compose build
```

it builds and pushes an image to our local docker registry.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-deploy.yml build &&
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-deploy.yml up -d
```

To deploy and run `application` pulled from the local registry rather than being rebuilt.

Unfortunately it rebuilds it because when I override `application`, `build` is still present as it is taken from `docker-compose.yml` file. 
How to I remove it ? Is there a way to do this - building and pushing and image using one docker-compose file and then only pull using docker compose file override ?

Comment: Why not remove the `docker-compose ... build` command from your deploy step?

Comment: How will it pull an updated image ?

Comment: Images are pulled from registries with the `pull` command, the `build` only pulls base images listed in your Dockerfile if they aren't already pulled.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, replacing `build` with `pull` did what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you let me, I found several things to consider. I don't know why do you want to have the same two build destination images but anyway I'll try to answer solutions better than ask why do you try to do that.

1. Changing image name you build different images. Maybe you could try with "deploy-version" for example.
2. If you don't want to change image name because you prefer (I don't know why) build it twice, you could try following command, setting different container_name in compose files:

> Furthermore, note that in your docker-deploy.yml file, for application service, you're not defining build section, so, `docker-compose -f docker-deploy.yml build` will build image with default `Dockerfile` and path: 
>   `.`

```
services:
  application:
    build: .
    image: localregistry:5000/mz_application:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
    container_name: app_compose
```

---

```
services:
  application:
    image: localregistry:5000/mz_application:latest
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
    container_name: app_deploy
```

3. Consider that multiple docker-compose build should be defined with different images. Maybe you are trying to deploy **different containers from the same image**. I see that only difference between application service definition in both docker-compose files is **ports declaration**, because `build: .` is the same that don't put anything. 
   When you use `docker-compose build` command, it ignores `ports:` section. When you use `docker-compose up` command, it ignores `build:` section.

Definitively, if you want to get up a concrete service without rebuilding avoiding image rewriting, you can also do:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-deploy.yml run -d nginx /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```